# Automatically Log Into Windows 10 At Specific Time

Tags: windows, windows-10, macros, login, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a macro to upload file to an website once a day on the weekend. I have created a macro with Pulover's Macro Creator that was successful in this.

My issue now is trying to find a way that my computer (Windows 10 Pro) will log into a specific user at a predetermined time. At that point a Scheduled Task will execute the macro and log off the machine.

Is there any way to do this?

I know that the macro itself will not be able to do this as it requires a user logged in with a visible window.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of a script the preferred option would be a script or batch files which does not require to use a ui. Then you could run it directly as planned task in Windows.

Comment: The script relies on screen coordinates. I don't think there is a way to send it with batch files or within powershell only. If you know a way i'd be glad to learn it.